# Can I use a user defined Environment variable inside requirements.txt as a conditional

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, environment-variables, requirements.txt

I have a usecase where I want to install one of pip package only when a condition passes.
Something like, export CI = true and then based on the value of "CI", I want to skip or install a package defined in requirements.txt.
I found the usage of environment markers but could not find something that fits my requirement. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could create an install.py script and call pip by script.

Comment: interesting, I will give it a try and get back here.